# Laravel 5.5 - Updating a pivot table with a custom field given two input arrays

Tags: arrays, input, eloquent, pivot-table, laravel-5.5

I have 2 input arrays, one for **ingredients** and one for the **amount** of the ingredient that is required for an associated recipe. My pivot table has four columns - `id`, `recipe_id`, `ingredient_id` and `amount`. I want to use the `sync` method to update the pivot table, however I can't work out how I would go about passing the second 'amounts' array values and ensuring they are synced with the correct record?

```
    $ingredients = $request->ingredients;
    $ingredientAmounts = $request->ingredients_amount;

    $project->ingredients()->sync( $ingredients => ['amount' => $ingredientAmounts] );
```

The ingredient and its amount will both have the same key so I guess I could loop through them manually and update the pivot table, but I feel like there will be a simpler way which will make better use of eloquent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two input arrays need to be merged to be in the format required:

`$user->roles()->sync([1 => ['expires' => true], 2, 3]);`

From https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships

```
    $array = [];

    foreach ($ingredients as $key => $ingredient) {
        $array[$ingredient->id] = ['amount' => $ingredientAmounts[$key]];
    }

    $project->ingredients()->sync($array);
```